# How to remove those vertices?

Tags: vertices

I'm new on Blender and I was following a tutorial to make a bottle, but I probably did a wrong shortcut and I ended up with unnecessary vertices giving this shape of houses/mountains, and I can't interact with them.

[image]

How do I remove them?
Or maybe I can delete linked vertices (the selected one on the screenshot) and then create new ones, but if I do that I don't know how to reconnect them to the rest of the bottle.

Thanks

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I suspect that image has just been created by the subsurf modifier. Try clicking the screen icon on the modifier to temporarily disable it. You also seem to have a keyframe on the modifier viewport level indicated by the green colour although I can't imagine why you would want one if you're just modelling a bottle! Can you add a link to the tutorial you're following as well as sharing the blend file.

Comment: Sure, here's the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dU6MSBjxUdU
And my file :
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2VReAE8k" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2VReAE8k/)

Comment: Oh yes indeed, this is because of the screen icon on the modifier. Why does it do that? Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John says, you have the *Subdivision Surface* modifier's *Edit Mode* option enabled, which, in *Wireframe* mode, will display the mesh as it will be if you applied it as well as the original mesh. So just disable this option:

[image]

Also note that the shapes that you are noticing belong to this inner face, as deformed by the modifier. Its vertices are almost overlapping with those of the cylinder, but most of all, this is not good topology, you should not have an inner face that make your object non-manifold. Anyway, I guess you didn't want it, so just delete it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!